# Why is go install writing binary in the src directory?

Tags: go

I have a small go program in the directory:

```
~/gocode/src/github.com/elviejo79/goexample/
```

When I execute

```
go install
```

The program does compile but it leaves the executable in the same directory as the code.

but according to [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html) the binary should in fact be saved at

```
~/gocode/bin
```

this my $GOPATH

```
$ echo $GOPATH
/home/agarcia/gocode
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cannot reproduce this. Please Enter

```
 $ go env
```

And verify where your GOBIN points to. For example, at the machine I'm right now, it says

```
09:01 myname@tux64:~$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/myname/bin"
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/myname"
GOROOT="/home/myname/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/myname/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
09:01 myname@tux64:~$
```

The go tool should send the binary to $GOBIN. Here it works like that.

Comment: and along these lines, after verifying the environment, you might want to make sure the binary you see isn't something left over from running `go build` in the past.

Comment: @jnml your instincts were correct my problem was that the $GOBIN variable wasn't set.
so simply in: .profile export GOBIN="$GOPATH/bin" and opening a new terminal fixed it. 
thank you very much.